# How to make round corner spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to make a round corner Spinner and i am trying using drawable xml file but ir didn't work for me?

By making drawable file but spinner didn't pick the xml file?

I want to make round corner Spinner..

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: You want to spinner data list round corner or only spinner view?

Comment: <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:background="@drawable/roundborder"/>

Comment: Only the spinner view

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.SplashActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

layout:

```
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_shape"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
```

shape layout_corners_shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <corners android:radius="3dp" />
   <solid android:color="#fff" />
   <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#d1d1d1"/>
</shape>
```

if didn't work, I think your shape's XML file copied in v24(or etc) folder

Comment: For some reason, the arrow down disappeared. Do you know how to make it visible again?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira add this to your selecter item                 <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_gray" />

Answer (score 1):

In your drawable **round_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="@dimen/_2sdp" />

<stroke
    android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:color="#939393" />
</shape>
```

And in layout xml file

```
 <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spProduct"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@drawable/spinner_drawable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add In your xml layout file to this code:-

```
enter code here <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/customspinner">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

After this Go drawable and make on custom file and put this code:-

```
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <padding />
                <solid android:color="@color/edittextcolor"></solid>
            </shape>
        </item>


        <item android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" android:gravity="right">

            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                <solid android:color="#d4dedf"></solid>
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"></corners>

            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```